# How to use Merge on partly serialized document in Doctrine ODM?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

Here is the use case. Some fields on the document are serializable/deserializable, others don't(see `@JMS\ReadOnly`).

```php
/**
 * @JMS\Groups({"board_list", "board_details"})
 * @JMS\Type("string")
 * @MongoDB\string
 */
protected $slug;

/**
 * @JMS\Groups({"board_list", "board_details"})
 * @JMS\ReadOnly
 * @MongoDB\Increment
 */
protected $views;
```

When in the controller I do an action to update the document:

```php
/**
 * [PUT] /boards/{slug} "put_board"
 * @ParamConverter("board", converter="fos_rest.request_body")
 * @Rest\Put("/boards/{slug}")
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=204)
 */
public function putBoardAction($slug, Board $board)
{
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
    $board = $dm->merge($board);
    $dm->flush();
    return true;
}
```

If the `views` field had some value before the action, after the action it gets reset to 0. How to avoid it? Is there a work-around Merge or Persist?

Answer (score 0):

If the `$views` property is read-only, and not set upon deserialization, it will be `0` at the time the action is invoked. When merging, ODM is first going to try to look up the Board document by its identifier. When it finds it in the database, its `$views` property will be the current value stored in the database. That document now becomes the managed copy that `merge()` will ultimately return. From there, we proceed to copy values from the Board document passed to `merge()`. In doing so, `$views` is set to `0`, over-writing whatever positive number it may have stored. When ODM goes to flush this change, it calculates the differences between the new and original values (likely the original view count multiplied by `-1`) and uses that for an `$inc`. That update brings the database value back to zero.

My advice would be to issue a separate update to increment `$views`, perhaps using the query builder. Even if `$views` was not read-only for the JMS Serializer service, you could still inadvertently decrement the counter if a Board with `$views` less than the corresponding database value was sent into the API.